# How does the class of Object retuned by python in-built function Iter() look like?

Tags: python, iterator

I am new into Python and I have understood the concepts of iterables and iterator objects. I understand all iterators are iterator itself but not all iterables are iterators like in the case of a list. My question is what happens behind the scenes when we call iter() on an iterables like list which doesn’t have the next() method defined in it. Apparently the iter() returns another object with the next() method defined it.
How does iter() takes an argument as list and returns an object that belongs to python’s in-built iter class having next() method defined.?
Thanks

```
def python_iterator(list_without_next_method):

    class iter2:
        def __init__(self, lst):
            self.lst=lst
            self.n=0
        def __nekst__(self):

            b=self.lst[self.n]

            self.n += 1
            return b

    iterator_object=iter2(list_without_next_method)
    return iterator_object
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
iterator=python_iterator(a)
print(iterator.__nekst__())
print(iterator.__nekst__())
print(iterator.__nekst__())
print(iterator.__nekst__())
print(iterator.__nekst__())
print(iterator.__nekst__())
print(iterator.__nekst__())
```

The above code is made as a way to make myself understand how the in-built iter() is working behind the scenes to make an object with next() method included.I have named my own iter-function as "python_iterator"(analogus to iter()). When this function is called it does exactly what the in-built iter() would do except that there is no code for Stopiteration inside my own next() function( nekst()).

Comment: In general, iterables do *not* have method `__next__` defined. According to the Python manual concerning iterables: **An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an __iter__() method or with a __getitem__() method that implements Sequence semantics.** In special cases, iterable object's `__iter__` method will return `self` when the class *does* define the `__next__` method.

Comment: (continued). That is when the iterator for the object is the object itself. Otherwise, `__iter__` will return a separate iterator object which does define `__next__`. Also: `next(obj)` results in the call:  `obj.__next__()`.  There is no `next` method defined on the object.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But just as you said, how does iter() return “ a separate iterator object which does define__next__()”?

Comment: By... using the `return` statement... to return... some different object... such that the class of that object... contains a definition for a `__next__` method. It means exactly what it says; I don't understand what confuses you about it.

Comment: dear @KarlKnechtel , again I m grateful for your effort in explaining things too.. I have edited my actual question and added some codes too. Please review th code and reflect on it.

Comment: Does https://treyhunner.com/2018/06/how-to-make-an-iterator-in-python/ help?

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Python lists are iterable, let's pretend they are not:

```
class MyList():

    class Iterator():
        def  __init__(self, lst):
            self.lst = lst
            self.index = -1
            self.max_index = len(lst)

        def __next__(self):
            self.index += 1
            if self.index == self.max_index:
                raise StopIteration()
            return self.lst[self.index]

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    def __iter__(self):
        return MyList.Iterator(self.lst)


l = MyList([0, 1, 2])
for i in l:
    for j in l:
        print (i, j)
```

Prints:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

**Important Note**

I should mention that implementing the iterator for `MyList` as a separate class that maintains its own state of iteration is what allows you to iterate an instance of `MyList` multiple time concurrently as in the above example.

Comment: That’s exactly how I thought it would be. When the for loop calls iter() on “l”  another object of class iterator() is returned which has next() defined in it. I just needed to know how it wud return an object with a different class and now it’s been cleared. Its been only two days since I started learning python and I am already addicted. I have no programming background except that i had learnt C programming back when I was in fourth semester of my engineering degree. Thanks everyone for helping me out.